# Proxy VPN settings in Network Manager: for remote or local?

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn, proxy, openvpn

So I am at some place with a normal (direct) internet connection and want to go through a remote network (my work) where I need a proxy to access the internet. Thus, I need to configure also a proxy when I connect through VPN. My question: the proxy settings in the network-manager dialog, is used for my outgoing connection from where I am physically or from the VPN-connected server?

Thanks